# submit job arrays in LSF

Tags: r, terminal, jobs, lsf

I have 12 folders that all contains one `R` file with the same name (e.g., `file.R`). The name of the folders are `m1`, `m2`, ..., `m12`. To run each file, I run `bsub -n 2 -q long -W 12:00 -R "rusage[mem=25000]" -M 25000 -hl R CMD BATCH file.R` in each folder. Is there a way to run it as a `job array` in the `LSF submission system` using `bsub`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to run it as a job array in the LSF submission system using bsub?

Yes there is.  Use `-J "[1-12]"` to run an array job.  The job will run 12 instances.  You'll need to write a simple script to set the CWD properly and then start `R`. Something like this should work.  The instance number is available through the environment variable `$LSB_JOBINDEX`.

```
$ cat runjob.sh 
#!/bin/sh

cd m${LSB_JOBINDEX}
exec R CMD BATCH file.R
```

and then submit your job like this

```
$ bsub -n 2 -q long -W 12:00 -R "rusage[mem=25000]" -M 25000 -hl -J "[1-12]" sh runjob.sh 
Job <1164> is submitted to queue <long>.
```

Comment: If I had two files in each folder, say `file.R` and `poo.R`, can I still just run them from the same `runjob.sh` script by simply adding another line with `exec R CMD BATCH poo.R`? Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  But remove the `exec`.  exec will replace the current process image with `R CMD BATCH file.R`.  So therefore none of the command after the first exec will be executed.  By removing the exec, a new process will be created to run `R CMD BATCH file.R`.   In your case file.R and poo.R will run sequentially.

Comment: How to do that in parallel instead of sequentially?

Comment: You could either run poo.R in a separate job array or run it in the same job array. If using the latter, you'll need some way to map the array index to poo.R or file.R